# Owl Slider - Duplicate Controls Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

firstly here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/krish7878/m2gnrx2v/1/

There are two instances of owl slider with custom controls each generated by its own code, the problem is, when the controls are clicked both the sliders respond instead of the respective slider responding.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="customNavigation">
    <a class="btn prev">
        <i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i>
    </a>
    <a class="btn next">
        <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
    </a>
```

**JS:**

```
    // Custom Navigation Events
$(".next").click(function(){
    slider1.trigger('owl.next');
})
$(".prev").click(function(){
    slider1.trigger('owl.prev');
})
```

The code is a bit long (but very simple), please have a look at the fiddle

This must be a javascript issue, something must be changed somewhere, I tried changing the class names of buttons but they stopped working.

Comment: _“I tried changing the class names of buttons but they stopped working”_ – then you did it wrong, because that definitively works.

Comment: @CBroe: Yes I did it wrong, I changed the "('owl.pre')" to "('owl.pre-2')".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(".next") action affects to all next css class. Use different CSS class or use a more complex expression like #slider1 > .next if buttons are inside the slider or changing .next with .nextslider1 and .nextslider2

example (http://jsfiddle.net/krish7878/m2gnrx2v/1/)

Html:

```
<div class="container">   
        <div id="slider-1">
            ...
        </div>
        <div class="customNavigation">
            <a class="btn prev1"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i></a>
            <a class="btn next1"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
       </div>
    </div> 
    ... 
    <div class="container">   
        <div id="slider-2">
           ...
        </div>
        <div class="customNavigation">
            <a class="btn prev2"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i></a>
            <a class="btn next2"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
       </div>
    </div>
```

Javascript:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {  

        var slider1 = $("#slider-1");
        slider1.owlCarousel({        
            autoPlay: 3000, 
            items : 5,
            pagination: false,
            stopOnHover: true,
            itemsDesktop : [1199,3],
            itemsDesktopSmall : [979,3]
        });

        $(".next1").click(function(){ slider1.trigger('owl.next'); });
        $(".prev1").click(function(){ slider1.trigger('owl.prev'); });

        var slider2 = $("#slider-2");
        slider2.owlCarousel({        
            autoPlay: 3000,
            items : 5,
            pagination: false,
            stopOnHover: true,
            itemsDesktop : [1199,3],
            itemsDesktopSmall : [979,3]
        });
        $(".next2").click(function(){ slider2.trigger('owl.next'); });
        $(".prev2").click(function(){ slider2.trigger('owl.prev'); });
    });
```

Also you can make it smaller using a function that composes each slider

```
    function doSlider(num){
        var slider = $("#slider-" +num);
        slider.owlCarousel({         
            autoPlay: 3000,
            items : 5,
            pagination: false,
            stopOnHover: true,
            itemsDesktop : [1199,3],
            itemsDesktopSmall : [979,3]
        });
        $(".next"+num).click(function(){slider.trigger('owl.next');});
        $(".prev"+num ).click(function(){slider.trigger('owl.prev');});
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {   
        doSlider(1);
        doSlider(2);
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

You use the same click event for each set of buttons.

I changed your html to:

```
<div class="customNavigation">
<a class="btn1prev">
    <i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i>
</a>
<a class="btn1next">
    <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
</a>
```

and the js accordingly:

```
// Custom Navigation Events
$(".btn1next").click(function(){
    slider1.trigger('owl.next');
})
$(".btn1prev").click(function(){
    slider1.trigger('owl.prev');
})
```

Notice the btn1next and btn1prev. I did the same thing for the 2nd buttons.

The js fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/krish7878/m2gnrx2v/1/